# TypeError: string indices must be integers Json.py

Tags: python, json

I get the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers" in the following code:

```
if body['category'] == 'Character':
        return sanic.response.json([], status=200)
```

Body:

```
{
        "lockerItem": "sandbox_loadout",
        "category": "Character",
        "itemToSlot": "AthenaCharacter:CID_279_Athena_Commando_M_TacticalSanta",
        "slotIndex": 0,
        "variantUpdates": [
                {
                        "channel": "Parts",
                        "active": "Stage0",
                        "owned": []
                }
        ],
        "optLockerUseCountOverride": -1
}
```

Full Error:

```
    if body['category'] == 'Character':
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Where do you get body from? It looks like it is still a json string. You need to get it converted to a dict.

Answer (score 1):

Verify your `body` variable type, the reason why you're getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers`  is because the `body` is of a string type and only integers indices can be used on a string.

You need to either convert your variable to a dict type where string indices can be used or ensure the variable you received is of a dict type

Comment: Exactly.  You can use the function `json.loads` to convert the string.